# Inherited Access Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

### Background

I am trying to set up inherited / referenced access in Firebase Firestore Security Rules.

In my example, I would like to control whether or not a user can update an "Hours" document depending on whether or not they are listed as an admin in the "Admins" subcollection of the "ServiceProvider" document referenced in the "Hours Document".

Ex: Hours document references a ServiceProvider document. Service Provider document has a subcollection "Admins" where the document Id of each "Admins" record is the authenticated UID.

### Problems

The logic works with a get method if I am the authenticated user, however if I am not, I get a null value exception as it can't find the document. I can use an exists method to check whether or not the document exists first, but then I run into an issue of how do I perform an if or ternary on the results of the exists method. I get unexpected values for both if and ternarys when inside one of the functions.

### Database Structure

*NOTE:* These are "Admins" to each service provider, a generic "role" set up is not meet the use case.

```
-ServiceProvider
-Admins (Subcollection)
--Id = Authenticated User Id
--Active = Boolean

-Hours
--mondayStart = String
--mondayEnd = String
--CreatedBy = (reference to ServiceProvider Document)
```

### Security Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
        match /databases/{database}/documents {

            function getAdminStatus(userId){
                //Get the Service Provider who Created the Hours Record
                let serviceProviderPath = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Hours/$(resource.id)).data.CreatedBy;

                //Get the Id of the Service Provider based on the Path Reference
                let serviceProviderId = get(serviceProviderPath).id;

                //Check if Authenticated User Id is in "Admins" subcollection of "ServiceProvider"
                let doesAuthenticatedUserExistInAdmins = exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/ServiceProvider/$(serviceProviderId)/Admins/$(userId));

                //How do I do this???  
                //Depending on whether user exists check if Active field is true and return the active results or false for exists  
                if (doesAuthenticatedUserExistInAdmins == true) {
                    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/ServiceProvider/$(serviceProviderId)/Admins/$(userId)).data.Active;
                }

                else {
                    return doesAuthenticatedUserExistInAdmins;
                }
        }

        function isUserAdminOfProvider() {
            let userId = request.auth.uid;
            return getAdminStatus(userId);
        }

        match /Hours/{Id} {
            allow write: if isUserAdminOfProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand, your use case doesn't work in case a user is not authenticated yet. Maybe using [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) would solve that issue for you?

Comment: @tzovourn, no. I am authenticated. Authenticated user does work, the issue is the syntax of the if and the null exception I receive when I test with an unauthenticated or non-admin authenticated user.

Comment: Could you point me to the documentation you followed to implement these rules? I have never seen a function written like this in [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#firestore)

Comment: @tzovourn https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions . The if else condition is theoretical of what I’m trying to do. I want to check for null and return different results based on that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check **whether a record exists** AND (`&&`) if it does exist, **whether or not the value is true**, you would use the following:

```
let doesExist = exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/ServiceProvider/$(serviceProviderId)/Admins/$(userId));
let isActive =  get(/databases/$(database)/documents/ServiceProvider/$(serviceProviderId)/Admins/$(userId)).data.Active;
return doesExist && isActive;
```

If you try to just `isActive` and return that, you may return a null which results in an exception, however, if you use the `&&` operator, null will return false and allow you to proceed without exception. A `null` is considered false in an expression, but returned directly is just `null`.